# How to allow anonymous access to static files using UseFileServer() when other endpoints still protected?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

In my ASP.NET Web API I have a default authorization policy that protects all endpoints:

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
   options.FallbackPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
       .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
       .RequireRole("defaultRole")
       .Build();
});
```

I also have a endpoint "/apidocs" that I now would like to be unprotected. It is configured using:

```
app.UseFileServer(new FileServerOptions
{
   FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(pathToDocs),
   RequestPath = "/apidocs",
});
```

What is the preferred way to solve this? This can be solved by calling:

```
.UseFileServer()
```

before calling:

```
.UseAuthorization()
```

but I think this is a ugly design that isn't explicit/clear enough.

Comment: I think this question has been explained in this document:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-6.0#static-file-authorization

Comment: what is not clear ?

Comment: It's not clear that "/apidocs" is unprotected.

Comment: In document: When the Static File Middleware is called before the authorization middleware.No authorization checks are performed on the static files.Static files served by the Static File Middleware, such as those under wwwroot, are publicly accessible.

Comment: UseFileServer combines the functionality of UseStaticFiles, UseDefaultFiles, and optionally UseDirectoryBrowser

Comment: Yes, I understand the document and the described concept. But I personally find it rather implicit and not clear which endpoints in the application that are protected or not. I would rather see an extension method ".AllowAnonymous()" on "UseFileServer", just like "MapHealthChecks().AllowAnonymous()" or similar.